# R MICE impute new observations

Tags: r, machine-learning, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

When I use the `mice` package to impute data I have the following issue:

I can't seem to find a way to replace `NA` values of new observations, given that I already have imputed the missing data in the training set.

## Example 1

I have trained an algorithm with data from data frame with 10 features and 1000 observations.

*How can I predict a new observation using this algorithm (with missing data)?*

## Example 2

Supose we have a data frame with `NA` values:

```
V1   V2  V3  R1
1    2   NA  1
1.4  -1  0   0
1.2  NA  0   1
1.6  NA  1   1
1.2  3   1   0
```

I impute the missing values using the `mice` package:

```
imp <- mice(df, m = 2, maxit = 100, meth = 'pmmm', seed = 12345)
```

The object `df` now has 2 dataframes with imputed values.

```
(dfImp1)
V1   V2  V3  R1
1    2   0.5 1
1.4  -1  0   0
1.2  1.5 0   1
1.6  1.5 1   1
1.2  3   1   0
```

Now with this data frame, I can train an algorithm:

```
modl <- glm(R1~., (dfImp1), family = binomial)
```

I want to predict the response of a new observation, e.g:

```
obs1 <- data.frame(V1 = 1, V2 = 1.4, V3 = NA)
```

*How do I impute the missing data a of new individual observation*?

Comment: Could you post some sample code, and a sample dataframe? Usually you use a predict() function on an algorithm with new data, but it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: I've added it at the op.

Comment: I've checked with Stefen Van Buuren, one of the creators of this package and he told me that is impossible. Sorry for the waste of time and thanks!

Comment: Depending on the type of relationship between the y variable and the x variables, you could maybe just use MICE on missing y variables for all new observations. The other way would be to just do the imputation on only x values, and then predict y after that, but this assumes that the missing x values have no additional relationship with the y besides their relationships with other x values (conditional on the non-missing x values, the missing x values have no effect on the y).

Comment: You'd have to impute the missing values of the new observation first.

Comment: yes!. that's the idea, but the thing is this: imagine that I have training and testing today, with that, I create the model that performs the best to predcit, but the new observations come tomorrow, and have null data, so I can't use the model that I've created today because I can't impute the data for the new observations, that would need to recreate a new model for each new observation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mice package has not a built-in solution but we can write one.

The idea is to:

- (1) use the same mice algorithm to fill NA in  dataset used to train GLM and the new observation(s);
- (2) predict only the new observation without NA.

I'm going to use iris as a data example.

```
library(R6)
library(mice)

# Binary output to use Binomial
df <- iris %>% filter(Species != "virginica")

# The new observation 
new_data <- tail(df, 1)

# the dataset used to train the model
df <- head(df,-1)

# Now, let insert some NAs
insert_nas <- function(x) {
  set.seed(123)
  len <- length(x)
  n <- sample(1:floor(0.2*len), 1)
  i <- sample(1:len, n)
  x[i] <- NA 
  x
}

df$Sepal.Length <- insert_nas(df$Sepal.Length)

df$Petal.Width <- insert_nas(df$Petal.Width)

new_data$Sepal.Width = NA

summary(df)
```

In fit method we apply mice to fill NAs, fit a GLM model and store it to be used in predict method.

In predict method we (1) add the new_observation to the dataset (with NAs), (2) replace NA again using mice, (3) get back the row(s) of the new observation(s) without NA and then (4) apply GLM to predict this new observation.

```
# R6 Class Generator
GLMWithMice <- R6Class("GLMWithMice", list(
  model = NULL,
  df = NULL,
  fitted = FALSE,
  
  initialize = function(df) {
    self$df <- df
  },
  fit = function(formula = "Species~.", family = binomial) {
    
    imp <- mice(self$df, m = 2, maxit = 100, meth = 'pmm', seed = 12345, print=FALSE)
    df_cleaned <- complete(imp,1)
    self$model <- glm(formula, df_cleaned, family = family, maxit = 100)
    self$fitted <- TRUE
    return(cat("\n model fitted!"))
  },
  predict = function(new_data, type = "response"){
    n_rows <- nrow(self$df)
    df_new <- bind_rows(self$df, new_data)
    imp <- mice(df_new, m = 2, maxit = 100, meth = 'pmm', seed = 12345, print=FALSE)
    df_cleaned <- complete(imp,1)
    new_data_cleaned <- tail(df_cleaned, nrow(df_new) - n_rows)
    return(predict(self$model,new_data_cleaned, type = type))
  }
  )
)
```

```
#Let's create a new instance of "GLMWithMice" class
model <- GLMWithMice$new(df = df)

class(model)
```

```
model$fit(formula = Species~., family = binomial)

model$predict(new_data = new_data)
```